# Unable to style react component using webpack

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

So I am trying to add some css style to my react components but failed. 
My webpack.config.js looks like:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, './build');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, './src/client');

const config = {
   entry: {
     main: APP_DIR + '/index.js'
   },
   output: {
     filename: 'bundle.js',
     path: BUILD_DIR,
   },
   module: {
    rules: [
     {
       test: /\.css$/,
       use: [{
           loader: "style-loader"
       }, {
           loader: "css-loader?modules=true&camelCase=true"
       }]
     },
     {
       test: /\.(jsx|js)?$/,
       use: [{
         loader: "babel-loader",
         options: {
           cacheDirectory: true,
           presets: ['@babel/preset-react']
         }
       }]
     }
    ],

  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

My client code folder looks like:

```
Client
--style
----index.css
--index.js
```

index.css looks like:

```
body{
    color: #555;
    background: #f85032;
    margin: 10px 30px;
}
```

Inside index.js, I am loading the css file using

```
import css from './style/index.css';
```

Then I do:

```
npx webpack
npm start
```

There's no error message in console output. The webpage shows up but there's no css style. Can someone please help me with this? Thanks!

It appears that if I do some inline css in index.html then it works? Any suggestion why this happens? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just guessing here, since i can not see your index.js

From your webpack file i can see that you are using css modules.
This means that you can not just assign classes as you would usually do it, but you must get them from the css you imported.

Hence

```
'<div className="className">'
```

Becomes

```
'<div class=Name"' + css.className + '">'
```

The reason is thay css modules is doing some clever naming to always make the imported css unique to ensure you are not having any global scoping and conflicts (which is what you want with css modules)

UPDATE

I have tried to create a local setup with your webpack config. You can download it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o0Alij7OEqUJUs0DARjWRezTlUIxadeh/view?usp=sharing) (It is just a zip file).

Unzip and enter folder then run `npm install` and `npm run webpack`. You can now open `build/index.html` and see the result.

Maybe then you can see what you are doing differently?

Comment: not sure what you mean. But right now inside my css file I only have a body selector and don't have any id or class selectors. Thanks!

Comment: It appears that if I do some inline css in index.html then it works? Any suggestion why this happens? Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you replace `loader: "css-loader?modules=true&camelCase=true"` with `loader: "css-loader"` in your webpack config

Comment: So I just did that but it does not fix the problem and nothing changed.

Comment: Just to make sure, you did also restart webpack right, just to make sure. However css modules might not be the problem if the other answer by Vu did not work. Inline styles work since that is not using your css files or  classes. The problem here seems to be that the css is not being loaded

Comment: So each time I would re-run the command npx webpack? So I guess I am restarting the webpack each time by doing this?

Comment: Yeah that should be no problem. I have just tried to make a local setup with the given webpack config, and here everything seems to work. I guess i have to understand a bit more about your project setup. What is your index.js file actually doing, and is body defined in some html file somewhere?

Comment: I have update the answer with how i made something work locally

Comment: Many Thanks! I think the reason is that I write my index.js using the "create-react-class". For some weird reason I still have to import 'react' to make the css thing work. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Change to `import './style/index.css';` and see if that works

Comment: Try changing `body{}` to `:global(body) {}` in `index.css` file @Rockingchief

Comment: It appears that if I do some inline css in index.html then it works? Any suggestion why this happens? Thanks!